# How to install SSL certificated created using little proxy in firefox and safari browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, browsermob-proxy, little-proxy

i am using browsermob proxy latest version with selenium script
i am intercepting http requests and adding custom headers on every request and routing all http and https traffic through browsermob proxy

when https request is made in firefox and safari i am getting ssl certificate error (when i checked in network tab manually i could see invalid ssl certificate error)

I checked Browsermob little proxy with mitm and created custom certificate .. when i install that test.cer file in browser manually by dragging certificate into browser then my testscript works fine

could you please help me out in this case how to import dynamically created test.cer file into firefox and safari browser?
or am i doing anything wrong in the approach itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a browser profile and import this certificate and use the same profile when you are starting the browser driver. This should solve your issue